# Um link para voltar um nível na hierarquia de pasta e ir para o nível abaixo em outra pasta

Tags: jsp

Olá.

O problema é o seguinte: dentro da pasta WebContent tenho a pasta hotel e dentro desta pasta hotel, tenho o arqivo cadastro_hotel.jsp.

Na raiz do WebContent, tenho a pasta menu e dentro desta pasta, tenho o arquivo menu_inicial.jsp. Eu criu um link, dentro do menu_inicial.jsp para apontar para hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp, mas não consigo. Já usei ../ e nada.

```
<a href="../hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp">Cadastrar hotel</a>
```

Ou seja, estou um nível abaixo em relação a raiz, quero voltar para a raiz e assim, descer o nível para a outra pasta. Eu consigo fazer a volta para a raiz usando ../, mas não consigo ir para o nível abaixo.

Comment: Qual é o endereço completo desses dois arquivos? ex: `www.exemplo.com/hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp` e `www.exemplo.com/menu/menu_inicial.jsp`? se for isso, você consegue usando somente a `/` e essa é a maneira ideal de organizar links: sempre comece com `/` e vá adicionando a partir daí. Isso é chamado de links absolutos, esses outros que tem `../` são chamados de relativos e geralmente causam problemas porque funcionam numa página, mas não na outra que está dentro de uma estrutura diferente.

Comment: @Michelle Akemi

Os links são: localhost:8080/sgh/hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp
No menu: localhost:8080/sgh/menu/menu_inicial.jsp
Ou seja, dentro da pasta webContent tem a pasta hotel e a pasta menu. Quero descobrir como ir e voltar entre estas duas pastas com o herf dos links.

Comment: Então use `/menu/menu_inicial.jsp` e `/hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp` nos links.

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="../menu/menu_inicial.jsp"></a>
```

e para a pasta hotel e o arquivo cadastro_hotel.jsp, fiz:

```
<a href="../hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp"></a>
```

O '../' volta para a pasta raiz, que neste caso é o webContent e daí é só colocar o caminho: /pasta/arquivo ou se estiver no mesmo nível, pasta colocar o nome do arquivo: /arquivo.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

No caso do JEE, o navegador "enxerga" sua aplicação a partir do WebContent. 
Como você está utilizando a tag 'a' (âncora) acaba gerando uma nova requisição de fora (do JSP/Java), ou seja, não é necessário utilizar o "../".

Apenas coloque `a href="hotel/cadastro_hotel.jsp"`

Caso você utilizando response.SendRedirect('caminho') ou request.forward(), aí sim teria que considerar a estrutura hierárquica do seu projeto, uma vez que você estaria fazendo uma requisição/redirecionamento via JSP.